# Mysql multi query getting err #1064 -

Tags: mysql

Help needed

When I am running this query I am getting an err Just simple update query that works fine if being running one by one.

```
update wp_posts 
set post_title = CONCAT(post_title,' Keyboard') 
where id = 67096 and NOT post_title like '%keyboard%'

update wp_posts 
set post_title = CONCAT(post_title,' Keyboard') 
where id = 67079 and NOT post_title like '%keyboard%'

update wp_posts 
set post_title = CONCAT(post_title,' Keyboard') 
where id = 67072 and NOT post_title like '%keyboard%'
```

I am getting this err msg

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update wp_posts set post_title = CONCAT(post_title,' Keyboard') where id = 67131' at line 2

THE important thing that when I run the query line one by one it works perfectly! If I run them all line by line the the query fails

Please help me understand the Issue

Thanks Asaf

Comment: Add `;` at the end of every Update statement

Answer (score 1):

If you run multiple `sql queries` together then add semicolon (;) after every sql query otherwise it will give error.

Try now.

```
update wp_posts set post_title = CONCAT(post_title,' Keyboard') where id = 67096 and NOT post_title like '%keyboard%';
update wp_posts set post_title = CONCAT(post_title,' Keyboard') where id = 67079 and NOT post_title like '%keyboard%';
update wp_posts set post_title = CONCAT(post_title,' Keyboard') where id = 67072 and NOT post_title like '%keyboard%';
```

Hope it will help.